# I cant get formik to import properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, formik

I am using react-native and installed formik using the command:
**"npm add formik yup @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons"**
in my project on vs code
when i first reloaded my project after creating a form it said:

**"formik could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules"**

I checked my package.json
and it says "formik": "^2.2.6"
and in my node_modules folder i found it. when i hover over the import statement it shows a path: **"/home/dean/Personal_Programming_Planner/node_modules/formik/dist/index"**

**Here is my code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ImageBackground, Image } from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";
// import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function CreateProjectScreen(props) {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      style={styles.background}
      source={require("../assets/background.jpg")}
    >
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ projectName: "Project Name" }}
        onSubmit={(data) => {
          console.log(data);
        }}
      >
        {({ values, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {/* <TextField
              name="projectName"
              value={values.projectName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            /> */}
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default CreateProjectScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm add` isn't the correct command, use `npm install formik yup`.